# Jquery Waypoints : Multiple functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I can only say that I testing waypoints and that as soon as I add a second function the first wont work anymore. Why is that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".black").waypoint(function(){
    TweenMax.to(this, 2, {right:"0", ease:Power2.easeInOut})       
},{offset:'50%'});

$(".white").waypoint(function(){
    TweenMax.to(this, 2, {left:"0", ease:Power2.easeInOut})       
},{offset:'50%'});

});
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery Waypoints are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I would be curious if the log will show its called more than once but the TweenMax is not able to execute multiple times.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".black").waypoint(function(direction){
    console.log('BLACK');
    TweenMax.to(this, 2, {right:"0", ease:Power2.easeInOut})       
},{offset:'50%'});

$(".white").waypoint(function(direction){
    console.log('WHITE');
    TweenMax.to(this, 2, {left:"0", ease:Power2.easeInOut})       
},{offset:'50%'});

});
```